# Is it possible to get a user's email address when authenticating them via the foursquare API?

Tags: authentication, foursquare

I want to allow users to sign up using foursquare, but I can't find where I'd get their email address from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, it should show up in the user resource, in the contact field: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/user

The email will only show up for the authenticated user, though.